# My React Nextjs web app is using up 100% of my ram and crashing when i try to do changes. Does anyone know how to fix this or what may be the cause?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am developping a web app using **reactjs** and **nextjs**. When i run it in dev mode, my ram is used up 100%. Im having a 12gb ram and almost 6gb is used up by node js runtime. My colleague has a 24gb ram and when he run it, node js uses almost 15gb ram. When a modification is done to the code, the node js runtime uses up 100% and everything else crashes.

The versions are as follows (as per package.json);
"next": "^13.2.1",
"react": "^18.2.0"

In the terminal, the below error is displayed.
`<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed`

Terminal log:

[image: Terminal log]

I have added the following code block to the next.config.js

```
webpack(config, { webpack }) {
    config.infrastructureLogging = { debug: /PackFileCache/ }; // Define infrastructureLogging inside the webpack function
    return config;
  }
```

According to those logs, when the web app starts, it creates a cache file and its size is almost 10gb. Everytime a change is made, the cache file is recreated.

Infrastructure Log:

[image: Infrastructure Log]